Site loads inconsistently
The site is loading inconsistently - 34ms then 84ms then over 3s. I ran it on redbot.com and got the following feedback:
"Content Negotiation(Content Negotiation response) The resource doesn't send Vary consistently."
When I mouse over the above a pop shows the following:
HTTP requires that the Vary response header be sent consistently for all responses if they change based upon different aspects of the request.
This resource has both compressed and uncompressed variants available, negotiated by the Accept-Encoding request header, but it sends different Vary headers for each;
accept-encoding, user-agent, user-agent when the response is compressed, and

user-agent, user-agent when it is not.
This can cause problems for downstream caches, because they cannot consistently determine what the cache key for a given URI is.
I don't what to do to correct this - any help would be greatly appreciated. I can upload my.htaccess file if needed.
Thank you.
